# Getting mouse position (column/rows character wise) in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking to get the mouse position within a bunch of characters within a div, which the user generates dynamically (like a text-editor). But I can't seem to find a function that lets you detect the column/rows of the mouse position within the text. I don't have a blinking cursor yet, I mean the literal mouse cursor. Since I'll need that to crate the blinking cursor on click and what not.

Comment: Are you using a monospace font? Normally text doesn't conform to columns. Do you mean position in the text? Also can't you just use a contenteditable div instead of whatever it is you are going to do? I get the feeling you are asking about [a solution for your actual problem not presented in your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I was just trying to see if anyone knows of a function that allows you to get the mouse position within the div so that when the user clicks, I know where to spawn the blinking cursor like you would see in creating a Stackoverflow reply which indicated where you are typing at. I'd use a textarea, but I'm working on something that will need the row/column of each new character typed. Thus, my first step is getting the mouse position within the text typed.